# Get emmeans of GAM with interaction in by argument

Tags: r, mgcv, emmeans

I have a GAM model (fitted with `mgcv`) which has an interaction of two factors in the `by` argument

```
gam(weight ~ s(Time, by = Diet:Treatment), data = dat)
```

If I try to extract the emmeans from that model it gives me an error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(tbl, , vars, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Here a fully reproducible example (with the `datasets::ChickWeight` data)

```
library(mgcv)
library(emmeans)

dat <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)
dat <- dat[dat$Chick %in% c(1:2, 21:22), ]
dat$Treatment <- factor(ifelse(dat$Chick %in% c(1, 21), "Control", "Treatment"))

fit <- gam(weight ~ s(Time, by = Diet:Treatment), data = dat)
emmeans(fit, specs = "Time", by = c("Diet", "Treatment"),
        at = list(Time = 0:20))
## renurns Error: undefined columns selected
emmeans::ref_grid(fit, at = list(Time = 0:20))
## renurns Error: undefined columns selected
```

Any idea why this is not working? Or is it a bug in the `emmeans::recover_data.gam()` function?

A simple workaround was to define a new factor but this is not convenient to make specific contrasts later.

```
dat$Diet_Treatment <- interaction(dat$Diet, dat$Treatment)
fit2 <- gam(weight ~ s(Time, by = Diet_Treatment), data = dat)
emmeans(fit2, specs = "Time", by = "Diet_Treatment",
        at = list(Time = 0:20))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but if you do `emmeans::ref_grid(fit, at = list(percent = 9:18))`, it will show you a summary of the reference grid obtained from the model you fitted, including the names of the variables you may legally use.  Perhaps `gam` already creates some variable for `source:treatment` that you may use as a `by` variable.

By the way, all the stuff with tibbles and pipes makes it a lot harder to see what you are doing. The issue you find is with `emmeans()`, and I'd appreciate if you kept the rest of it plain-vanilla.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I replaced the simulated dataset with a modification existing dataset to have less tibbles and pipes. The question remains the same. `emmeans` returns an error, also with the `ref_grid` function. Did you try to run the example?